# Determine Socket from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu, intel-celeron

Is there a simple way to determine the CPU socket from the output of `/proc/cpuinfo`.  Determining the type of processor is simple enough, but the processor I have (Celeron) has two different possible sockets.  The output of `/proc/cpuinfo` is:

```
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 15
model : 4
model name : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.66GHz
stepping : 9
cpu MHz : 2672.411
cache size : 256 KB
fdiv_bug : no
hlt_bug : no
f00f_bug : no
coma_bug : no
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat     pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc up pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 cid cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips : 5344.82
clflush size : 64
power management:
```

I've looked on the Intel processor finder web site with [appropriate filters](http://processorfinder.intel.com/List.aspx?ParentRadio=All&ProcFam=49&SearchKey=), but the stepping values do not appear to match anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lshw will show you the socket

```
sudo lshw -class cpu
```